# SQL CASE WHEN columnvalues = totalcolumnvalues +- 1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

I need some help figuring out how to do a plus/minus 1 range in my query.

I am trying to make something like the below to work

```
SELECT 

CASE WHEN (columnvalues1 + columnvalues2 + columnvalues3) = totalcolumnvalues +- 1 THEN 1 END AS flag

FROM table1
```

so if the result is 37, then a 36, 37 or 38 will be within the +- 1 range and therefore flagged

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the total is a float or decimal you can simply use a `BETWEEN` clause:

```
CASE WHEN columnvalues1 + columnvalues2 + columnvalues3 BETWEEN
    totalcolumnvalues - 1 AND totalcolumnvalues + 1
THEN ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it always happens to me, the answer is easier than I was originally overthinking it.

Your second option was the one I was looking for as it also allows floats to work within the +- 1 range

Answer (score 0):

use ABS:

```
CASE WHEN ABS( (columnvalues1 + columnvalues2 + columnvalues3) - totalcolumnvalues )<=1
  THEN 1 END AS flag
```